# Is possible to pass a variable from a Build to a Release in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, release, ms-release-management

A Build definition has a custom variable that can be set when a build is queued.

Is possible to have access to that variable from a Release in the same way that is possible to have access to variables like Build.DefinitionId, Build.DefinitionName, Build.BuildNumber ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom build variable couldn't be used in your release definition. Here is an user voice that similar to your problem: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14515326-project-level-build-release-variables. You could vote and add comment below.

As a workaround, you could copy those build variables and their values to a [Variable groups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/variable-groups). Then add the Variable group to your release definition.
This is a new feature in TFS 2017 Update1.

Comment: The variable groups are a great option, to share values among releases, but when it came to share information between a build and a release, they are useless

Comment: How do you get variable from specific Build (like artifact) and not just shared static value from Variable group? Is it possible?

Comment: @Tingting0929 link is not available now

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to do this with an extension from the TFS marketplace, called 'Variable (de|re)Hydration Tasks', from naked Agility Ltd. This extension provides build- and release tasks with which you basically can save your build variables and restore them in your release.
It does this by prefixes, so you can save/restore all default build variables that are prefixed with 'BUILD-', but if you prefix your own variables with i.e. 'ABC_' you can also save them from your build and restore them in your release.

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried just passing the variable into the task definition like `$(MyVariable)` (where MyVariable is the custom variable name)?

Comment: Even as $(Build.MyVariable)