# TFS. Pass variable from triggered build to next task in a release

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, release-management

I want to pass variable between release tasks. (from triggered build to script)

Files:

**Script1**:  (saves a env variable)

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyVar;]$MyVarValue")
```

**Script2**:  (prints the env variable value)

```
Write-host $env:MyVar
```

**Script3**:  (same as Script2)

```
Write-host $env:MyVar
```

***First approach: build***

- MyBuild:

  - Script1
  - Script2

This is working properly, the second script writes the value of $env:MyVar created in the first.

***Second Approach: release***
 - MyRelease:

- Script1
- Script2

Also works properly.

My problem comes when my release changes to:

- MyRelease:

  - Triggered_build (MyBuild)
  - Script3

In that last case, the Script3 is not printing the $env:MyVar, so I guess that release uses a different environment than the used for the triggered build?

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: What is the information you're trying to pass from build to release? There may be a better way of achieving your desired results.

Comment: is a variable calculated when the build is executed, a path

Comment: @Ale Xis, Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please mark your solution as an answer, so it could help other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do that directly with TFS.

I have read about variable groups, but is not possible to set the variables dynamically in execution time with a script.

The only solution found is using the plugin **Variable (de|re)Hydration Tasks**

Solution from: [Is possible to pass a variable from a Build to a Release in TFS 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43496281/is-possible-to-pass-a-variable-from-a-build-to-a-release-in-tfs-2017)